# How to copy/put required file and directory in bin/release folder in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have created a new project in Visual studio 2013. I am using SVN tool for manage this project. one of the my calig has committed whole project on SVN. But I have read on internet[[What Visual Studio files should be ignored by subversion to minimize conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588077/what-visual-studio-files-should-be-ignored-by-subversion-to-minimize-conflicts]) bin,obj folder is created automatically when build the project so need to upload this type of folder in SVN. So,I have added bin and obj directory in ignored list. 
I am using bin/release for create setup. Bin/release directory created successfully when I am build but getting so many errors due some of the .DLL file is missing, images missing because I have removed/ignore this files from SVN.

So, Is there any way like when I build the project in visual studio it will copy/put all required files in bin/release directory ? otherwise I need to remove this folder from ignore list and commit all the files on svn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Post build event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.120).aspx) for organising the output after compile. It's just the batch script which you invoke from post build event, while writing the script you can use macros for getting the solution dir, out dir,.. as mentioned in the link.

You can access post build event UI in VS by Project Properties->Configuration Manager (choose the target to build) -> Build Events -> Post Build Events.